# Как создать список из случайных целых чисел используя списковое включение?

Tags: python, случайные-числа, список

Я хочу создать список, состоящий из, например, двадцати элементов. Каждый элемент должен быть произвольным целым числом от -10 до 10.

```
from random import randint

numbers = []
for i in range(20):
    numbers.append(randint(-10, 10))
```

Или так:

```
from random import randint
lst = [randint(-10, 10) for i in range(20)]
```

Как  сделать то же самое, только что бы это было в одну строку (за исключением импортов) (например используя списовое включение, генераторное выражение, какие-нибудь функции из функций `map()`, `zip()`, функции из `itertools`) и не было промежуточной переменной `i`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import timeit, random, itertools, operator, functools, numpy

a, b, s = -10, 10, 1000
v1=lambda: list(numpy.random.randint(a, b, s))
v2=lambda: [random.randint(a, b) for _ in range(s)]
v3=lambda: list(map(lambda _: random.randint(a, b), range(s)))
v4=lambda: list(itertools.starmap(lambda: random.randint(a, b), [()]*s))
v5=lambda: list(r(a, b) for r in [random.randint]*s)
v6=lambda: [r() for r in [functools.partial(random.randint, a, b)]*s]
v7=lambda: list(operator.methodcaller('__call__', a, b)(r) for r in [random.randint]*s)
v8=lambda: list(map(operator.methodcaller('__call__', a, b), [random.randint]*s))
v9=lambda: list(map(operator.methodcaller('__call__'), [functools.partial(random.randint, a, b)]*s))
v10=lambda: numpy.random.randint(a, b, s).tolist()

def execTime(target_: list, repeat=1):
    for n, fn in target_: print(n, timeit.Timer(fn).timeit(1), fn())
    target_[:] = [(n, timeit.Timer(fn).timeit(repeat)) for n, fn in target_]
    for e, (n, tmt) in enumerate(sorted(target_, key=lambda r: r[1]), start=1):
        print("{}'time {} {}".format(e, n, tmt))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    target = [(n, fn) for n, fn in sorted(globals().items()) if n.startswith('v')]
    execTime(target, repeat=100)
```

out:

```
v1 0.00013895335493526386 [8, 6, 8,..]
 ...
v9 0.0034144395633564986 [-8, 3, -3,..]
1'time v10 0.005898359039140072
2'time v1 0.014917592744244368
3'time v5 0.32350102439781625
4'time v2 0.33059889747340865
5'time v4 0.3355538953844154
6'time v8 0.34316236373969566
7'time v3 0.3506998448115352
8'time v6 0.3632192647513499
9'time v9 0.3795784125105248
10'time v7 0.4123779585340184
```

Comment: Спасибо, узнал много нового!

Comment: @pynix `map()` не возвращает список в Питоне 3. Для переносимости лучше использовать `[randint(-10, 10) for _ in range(20)]` вариант, приведённый в вопросе. Если хотите, опубликуйте это как свой ответ (замените i на _). Использование подчёркивания является принятым соглашением для подобных случаев в Питоне.

Comment: Я понял, что имел ввиду vadim vaduxa. С другой стороны действительно, это фактически то же самое, что написал я, за исключением замененного обозначения переменной i на _. Но так я узнал, что это обозначение является общепринятым для подобных случаев, то меня перестало терзать использование "паразитной" переменной. Я буду использовать его в дальнейшем.

Comment: у NumPy есть встроенный метод для конвертирования `array` в `list` - `array.tolist()`. Попробуйте заменить: `list(numpy.random.randint(a, b, s))` --> `numpy.random.randint(a, b, s).tolist()` - должно быть в 1.5-2 раза быстрее для такого к-ва элементов...

Comment: действительно, спасибо

Answer (score 8):

Можно воспользоваться NumPy:

```
import numpy as np

lst = np.random.randint(-10, 10, 20)

print(lst)
```

можно и матрицы легко создавать:

```
In [3]: np.random.randint(-10, 10, (5,3))
Out[3]:
array([[-10,   2,   8],
       [ -8,  -3,   8],
       [ -1,   8,   8],
       [  8,   9,  -7],
       [  4,   5,  -4]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Подходит, если требуется сформировать выборку без повторения.

```
from random import sample

list = sample(range(-10, 11), 20)
```

Comment: а sample(range(-10, 11), 1000) уже не работает

Comment: @vadimvaduxa спасибо, что обратили внимание. Мой ответ не является корректным на поставленный вопрос.